# Random number generators for a skiplist implementation

Tags: swift, random, skip-lists

Most skiplists guides I see use an LCG random number generator and the following formula to generate the node heights.

```
random.generate().trailingZeroBitCount + 1
```

But LCGs have bad randomness in the lower order bits. Is this a problem, and if so what’s a good random number generator for skiplists?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `trailingZeroBitCount` then you are going for a specific distribution.  In a random sample, we'd expect half of the numbers (the odd ones) to have `trailingZeroBitCount == 0`.  We'd expect 1/4 of them to have `1` and so on.

I put this in a playground and got that distribution:

```
let randos = (1..<100000).map { _ in return arc4random() }

let zeroZeros = randos.filter{ i in i % 2 == 1 }
zeroZeros.count

let oneOrMoreZeros = randos.filter{ i in i % 2 == 0 }.map { $0 / 2 }
let oneZero = oneOrMoreZeros.filter{ i in i % 2 == 1 }
oneZero.count

let twoOrMoreZeros = oneOrMoreZeros.filter{ i in i % 2 == 0 }.map { $0 / 2 }
let twoZero = twoOrMoreZeros.filter{ i in i % 2 == 1 }
twoZero.count
```

[image: Playground run of the above code]

I used arc4random because I don't know what you are using. Use this code to check your random number generator gets this kind of distribution.

Comment: it’s not as much about the distribution as it is about the pattern. You can get a *perfect* distribution by just counting upwards from 0 and taking the `trailingZeroBitCount` but nobody does that. Speaking of that, `rand()`/`arc4random()` produces the height sequence `1
2
1
3
1
2
1
4
1
2
1
3
1
2
1
5
1
 …` on poor seeds

Comment: @taylorswift I don't understand your comment - arc4random doesn't have seeds.

Comment: arc4random has a seed, it's just seeded automatically for you.

Comment: @LouFranco Yes, I should have said "externally controllable seeds".  I still fail to grasp what is meant by "poor seeds" when talking about a generator that is polling kernel randomness to stir the pot.

Comment: @taylorswift sometimes sees bad sequences when only considering the lower-order bits.  These bad sequences are the ones they are saying have poor seeds.  "poor seeds" for the purpose of using low order bits to come up with a sequence for skip-lists

Comment: @taylorswift How about GameplayKit's GKShuffledDistribution: `let source = GKShuffledDistribution(lowestValue: 0, highestValue: 1000)` then `source.nextInt()`

Comment: @LouFranco if it helps, i am not developing on Linux, not an Apple platform so i’m more interested in  RNG algorithms, not specific frameworks

Comment: The algorithm is generate the numbers and then shuffle them.  When you run out, generate and shuffle.

Comment: @LouFranco If taylor swift sometimes sees sequences s/he doesn't like they derive from the sequence of states the generator hits. It's an abuse of the terminology to call that bad seeds, particularly given that if you ran it again you'd never see the same sequence.  It's certainly not what people like Devroye or L'Ecuyer mean by the term "seed".